# mysql recreating dropped table and altering existing one

Tags: java, mysql, database, innodb

I hope I can explain what is happening clearly. I searched and haven't found this problem mentioned anywhere (but I admit I have poor search skillz.) MySQL is creating a dropped table and changing the engine on another from MyISAM to InnoDB.

A bit of history:

I am developing a Java application using MySQL under NetBeans on a Linux Mint system. I blindly started using MySQL without changing the default directory (/var/lib/mysql) which had 2 GB to spare. Pretty soon it filled up with the InnoDB ibdata stuff so I disabled InnoDB using instructions found here on StackOverflow and deleted the files. A bit later I filled up the partition with my tables so I dedicated a whole hard drive to the database. Somewhere along the way I created a table called 'portfolio' from the MySQL command line. I then decided to drop it and create a new one called 'portfolios' (plural). Then about a week ago I decided to give InnoDB another try, ran with it for a day or two then decided to disable it again.

Now about once a day I get "Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'"
on 'portfolios' and a 'show tables' command lists both 'portfolio' and 'portfolios'. I drop them both and issue a new create command on 'portfolios' and everything runs fine. I even rebooted the machine and everything was fine. Then yesterday I got the "unknown engine InnoDB" error out of the blue and had to go through the process again. I booted up this morning and everything ran fine. Just now, I had to shut the machine off and after turning it back on got the error yet again and the 'portfolio' table reappeared. Also the describe command for 'portfolio' is for yet another table that is created in a Java program using the memory engine, not the original way it was created.

It seems like MySQL has some old information squirreled away somewhere and wants to resurrect it every once in awhile. Any ideas where to look or how to fix this?

Thanks for any help, this is my first post here but I have found a lot of valuable info here in the past few weeks.am

Comment: Is your Java code altering your db schema? Have you attempted a fresh install of MySQL?.

Comment: Java code is not directly altering the schema. I may have discovered the problem - I went into MySQL Workbench and saw that the old ibdata was listed as a schema. I deleted anything "ib*" and will see what happens. Yesterday I had renamed some columns in several tables and today they had reverted back to the old names. Edit: to be more clear, yesterday I renamed the columns in the Java code and rebuilt the tables from scratch. Today they had the old column names.

Comment: I did 'show table status' and there were three tables from early 2011 that showed "unknown engine InnoDB" but there were many more that hadn't been used since then that showed MyISAM. I dropped those tables and hope I never have to rebuild them again. I then tried to mysqldump just the schema and there was an error at 'portfolios'. I can't get the error message as it has scrolled off the screen. I dropped 'portfolios', created it again and the schema dump worked. I decided to dump the whole database and reload it.

Comment: In case anyone is reading, I did dump the DB, dropped it and reloaded. It worked fine for a day and today it is back to thinking 'portfolios' uses InnoDB. I also moved a bunch of old tables to another DB and the are back, both in the schema and the data tables. Time to fix it, dump again, and reinstall MySQL. Or consider switching to another DB.

Comment: I would be curious if a full re-install of mysql fixes this problem. I am not used to db engines just changing themselves to innodb and dont see how that is possible without outside influence?

Comment: I am restoring the database now after re-installing. I did run across something that might be causing the problem. Before I disabled InnoDB the second time I tried recovering from the errors I was getting. I had left 'innodb_force_recovery=0' in my.cnf.

Comment: interesting, if that turns out to be it, be sure to answer your own question to help others

Comment: This is getting more strange. Before re-installing I did 'mv /database/mysql /database/oldmysql' to preserve a copy of the old data. Just now the old tables that I had moved to another DB are back, it's complaining about no InnoDB again, *AND /database/oldmysql IS GONE*. Actually I think the new mysql directory is gone and the old one has been renamed as the ib_logfiles and ibdata crap is back with old timestamps.

Comment: OK, this HAS to be the problem. I use a backup program (luckyBackup). I had first moved from /var/lib to another directory off of root '/database'. I then decided to dedicate a whole drive for database work. After setting up the drive I simply set up a restore task in luckyBackup and mounted the drive on '/database'. Looks like the restore task was scheduled to run everyday at 3pm. that would explain why everything would be OK when I first booted the computer in the morning but went bad later in the day.

Answer (score 0):

The luckyBackup restore mentioned in my last comment looks to be the problem. I removed it from the schedule and everything has been running fine for over a day now.

In the meantime it has given me incentive to try H2. It is much faster building large tables from scratch (like 41 minutes vs 77 minutes for MySQL) but slower at some other things. It has also forced me to learn and use more standard SQL statements.